# A = UL factorization

Tags: matrices

How do I calculate $A=UL$ factorization where $U$ is upper triangular matrix with 1's along the diagonal and $L$ is lower triangular matrix?

How is this similar to the $LU$ factorization?

Comment: Start at the bottom and work your way up?  The last row of $U$ has to be $(0,0,\ldots,1)$, so the last row of $L$ is.... the same as the last row of $A$.  What can you do with the last column of $L$?

Answer (score 10):

If you already know how to get an $LU$ factorization, then one approach to getting your $UL$ factorization is by similarity transformation.

Let $B = PAP$ where $P$ is the [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) with 1's on the anti-diagonal and 0's elsewhere.  Thus $P = P^T = P^{-1}$, and $B$ is orthogonally similar to $A$.

If $B = LU$ is a factorization with lower triangular $L$ having 1's along the diagonal, and $U$ an upper triangular matrix, then by similarity:

$$ A = (PLP^T)(PUP^T) $$

Note that $PLP^T$ is an upper triangular matrix with 1's along the diagonal, and $PUP^T$ is a lower triangular matrix, so the above is a factorization of the desired form.